# get a random query result and then sort it

Tags: php, pdo

I need to run an ORDER BY RAND query and then sort the resulting data set numerically. In other words I want a random set of data (in this case 7 numbers), but then I need to sort those 7 results numerically.

**After this code runs:**

```
if ($today == "Oct 31") { 

  $dayList = "halloween"; 
  $stmt = $pdo->query("SELECT `rand` FROM `jukebox2014` 
           WHERE `class` = '$dayList' ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 7");
}
```

**I need to sort the 7 results.**

Any ideas?

Thanks.

Comment: So, what you are trying to do is fetching 1, 7, 3, 4, 2, 5, 6 and then order them back 1 - 7?

Comment: Have you made any attempt to do this yourself?

Comment: Yeah, I've been trying for 2 days. Nothing yet works.

Comment: If you've tried something, it really helps to show what you've tried and explain in what way it fails to accomplish what you want. For example, give your code, some sample data, desired/anticipated results, and undesired/actual results.

Comment: I'm trying to query a 500 record mySQL db to get 7 random records---which happen to be numbers---and then I want to sort them numerically. Finally, I want to export the sorted "array" as a text file. The full code for the original query INCLUDING the write-to-textfile function is this:   if ($today == "Oct 31"){$dayList = "halloween"; $stmt = $pdo->query("SELECT `rand` FROM `jukebox2014` WHERE `class` = '$dayList' ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT $limit");}
$fh = fopen("dataPDO.txt", "w"); while ($row = $stmt->fetchObject()) {fwrite($fh, $row->rand.",");} fclose($fh); exit();

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As simple as:

```
SELECT `rand`
FROM (
    SELECT ... ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 7
)
ORDER BY `rand`
```

Not that `ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 7` is a rather inefficient method to select random data; more efficient methods will depend on your exact data. Search Stackoverflow for many questions regarding this topic.

Comment: This didn't work but maybe I don't really understand the syntax you suggest. And I think I should have posted ALL the code with my original question. Here's the code (with your suggestion included). if ($today == "Oct 31"){$dayList = "halloween"; $stmt = $pdo->query("SELECT `rand` FROM `jukebox2014` WHERE `class` = '$dayList' ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT $limit ORDER BY `rand`");}  $fh = fopen("dataPDO.txt", "w"); while ($row = $stmt->fetchObject()) {fwrite($fh, $row->rand.",");} fclose($fh); exit();

Comment: THIS WORKED! Took me a while to figure out the proper syntax, but it works great. I will look into RAND() alternatives soon.

Comment: This is a great resource and I appreciate your help.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you mean.

```
$new = array();
foreach ($results as $result) {
    $new[] $result['rand'];
}

$sorted = ksort($new);
```

Comment: Appreciate all the help (so quickly) and apologize for a hobbyists ignorance. I should have included ALL the code. Here's what's missing. It is code to write the (hopefully) sorted array to a text file. --- $fh = fopen("dataPDO.txt", "w"); while ($row = $stmt->fetchObject()) {fwrite($fh, $row->rand.",");} fclose($fh); exit();